# AD integration in RHEL 7 without Kerberos

Tags: active-directory, ldap, su

How to integrate with AD in RHEL 7 without kerberos? I have below in `/var/log/secure`.

```
Mar 12 09:57:31 xxxxxxxx su: pam_sss(su-l:auth): authentication failure; logname=admin uid=86500 euid=0 tty=pts/0 ruser=admin rhost= user=rajesh
Mar 12 09:57:31 xxxxxxxx su: pam_sss(su-l:auth): received for user rajesh: 6 (Permission denied)
Mar 12 09:57:31 xxxxxxxx su: pam_sss(su-l:auth): authentication failure; logname=admin uid=86500 euid=0 tty=pts/0 ruser=admin rhost= user=rajesh
Mar 12 09:57:31 xxxxxxxx su: pam_sss(su-l:auth): received for user rajesh: 6 (Permission denied)
Mar 12 09:57:34 xxxxxxxx su: FAILED SU (to rajesh) admin on pts/0
```